# Check if input string has leading or trailing whitespaces in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stdstring

I am trying to validate a **single-line** input string in C++11 to see if it contains any leading / trailing whitespaces. My code now looks like this:

```cpp
bool is_valid(const std::string& s) {
    auto start = s.begin();
    auto end = s.end();
    if (std::isspace(*start) || std::isspace(*end)) {
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}

int main() {
    std::string name{};
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    if (!is_valid(name)) {
        std::cout << "Invalid!";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But now the program can only detect leading whitespaces. For example, for    `John` it would print `Invalid!` but for `Mary`    it would classify it as valid input, which is not. Does anyone know what's wrong with my program?

Comment: Use `back()` to check the last character and ditch the `end()` iterator.

Comment: `return s.empty() || (!std::isspace(s.front()) && !std::isspace(s.back()));`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple test for [std::string::front()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/front) and [std::string::back()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/back) could have been done after testing for the empty string:

```
bool is_valid(const std::string& s) 
{
   return s.empty() || 
    (!std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(s.front())) && 
     !std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(s.back())));
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit more on why you choose use `static_cast<unsigned char>` for the statement? Wouldn't the simple `std::isspace(s.front())` be enough?

Comment: [See this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace), and read the **Notes** section at the link.

Comment: I wonder why they don't provide the safe functions in C++...

Comment: Not sure -- it probably has to do with legacy `C` treating characters as `int`, and C++ adopting what `C` did.   There more than likely is a good reason, since on the surface it would look like C++ could provide safe functions.

Answer (score 4):

The end iterator does not point to an element in the container. It points one past the last element. You may not dereference the end iterator. For a `std::string` you can use it's `operator[]`:

```
char last_char = s[s.size()-1];
```

advance the begin iterator:

```
auto it = s.begin() + s.size()-1;
char last_char = *it;
```

or decrement the end iterator:

```
auto it = s.end() -1;
char last_char = *it;
```

Other alternatives are `back()` or using the reverse iterator `rbegin()`.

Note that they all require `s.size() != 0`. For an empty string `s.begin() == s.end()`. You should check that first in the function and return `true` for that case.

Answer (score 3):

[`s.end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/end) is *one pass the end of the string* just like any other containers in C++, so accessing it invokes undefined behavior. You need to use `std::prev(s.end())` instead (which is valid only the string contains at least 1 character though, so you need to check the string length first)

Answer (score 2):

`.end` is used to get an iterator to past the last element. You can use [`std::string::rbegin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin) to get the last element.

```
auto end = s.rbegin();
```

---

<sub>**NB:** [`std::string::starts_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/starts_with) and [`std::string::ends_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/ends_with) are available from C++20.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `.end()` is to the past-the-end element. Then why not using `.back()` instead?

```cpp
bool is_valid(std::string const& str) {
    return str.empty() || !(std::isspace(str.front()) || std::isspace(str.back()));
}
```